# Python search HTML document for capital letters

Tags: python, regex, coda, letters, capitalize

So I have all these html documents that have strings of capital letter in various places in alt tags, title tage, link text...etc.

```
<li><a title='BUY FOOD' href="http://www.example.com/food.html'>BUY FOOD</a></li>
```

What I need to do is replace all letters except the first letter with lowercase letting. Like so:

```
<li><a title='Buy Food' href="http://www.example.com/food.html'>Buy Food</a></li>
```

Now how can I do this either in python or some form of regex. I was told that my editor Coda could do something like this. But I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do something like this.

Comment: After reading you citing HTML and regex in the same question, I have to link to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use Beautiful Soup to parse your HTML into a tree of tags, then write Python code to walk the tree of tags and body text and change to title case.  You could use a regexp to do that, but Python has a built-in string method that will do it:

```
"BUY FOOD".title()  # returns "Buy Food"
```

If you need a pattern to match strings that are all caps, I suggest you use: `"[^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*"`

This means "match zero or more of anything except a lower-case character, then a single upper-case character, then zero or more of anything except a lower-case character".

This pattern will correctly match "BUY 99 BEERS", for example.  It would not match "so very quiet" because that does not have even a single upper-case letter.

P.S. You can actually pass a function to `re.sub()` so you could potentially do crazy powerful processing if you needed it.  In your case I think Python's `.title()` method will do it for you, but here is another answer I posted with information about passing in a function.

[How to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-python/1549983#1549983)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a HTML parser like **BeautifulSoup**, the rest would be details.

Comment: I have been using BeauitfulSoup. But can't seem to get the regex right.

Answer (score 0):

There may be noteworthy exceptions for which fully automatic editing is not a good idea, but if you have a regex capable editor you might search for /[A-Z][A-Z]+/ and replace by hand.