# How to capitalize some words in a text file?

Tags: python, formatting, python-2.7, text-manipulation

I have a text file which have normal sentences. Actually I was in hurry while typing that file so I just capitalized the first letter of first word of the sentence (as per English grammar).

But now I want that it would be better if each word's first letter is capitalized. Something like:

> Each Word of This Sentence is Capitalized

*Point to be noted in above sentence is **of** and **is** are not capitalized, actually I want to escape the words which has equal to or less than **3** letters.*

What should I do?

Comment: "I want to escape the words which has equal to or less than 3 letters." - there are words with more than 3 characters that should not be capitalized in a title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split the words, and capitalise only those which are longer than three letters.

`words.txt`:

```
each word of this sentence is capitalized
some more words
an other line
```

-

```
import string


with open('words.txt') as file:
    # List to store the capitalised lines.
    lines = []
    for line in file:
        # Split words by spaces.
        words = line.split(' ')
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if len(word.strip(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)) > 3:
                # Capitalise and replace words longer than 3 (without punctuation).
                words[i] = word.capitalize()
        # Join the capitalised words with spaces.
        lines.append(' '.join(words))
    # Join the capitalised lines.
    capitalised = ''.join(lines)

# Optionally, write the capitalised words back to the file.
with open('words.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(capitalised)
```

Comment: Close, but what about punctuation increasing the letter count of a "word"?

Comment: Almost perfect except for embedded punctuation (i.e. "can't"). +1 anyway.

Comment: @ArturGaspar How do I prevent this script form writing/printing a blank line at last.

Comment: @Santosh Remove a blank line from the input file.

Comment: @ArturGaspar My input file has no **blank line**, just a single line of small case words.

Comment: @Santosh And the output still contains an extra blank line? Strange, I've tested it before replying to your comment and it worked fine. Can you test it writing to a file instead of printing it?

Comment: OK! I apologize. I have modified this script a bit. [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/UpWPNmfK). Can you debug it?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Instead of `os.linesep.join(lines)` you should use `''.join(lines)`.

Comment: This is not working as well. Did you seen my modified script?? I am passing argument to script. Bye the way your script was working well before too. But its writing blank line at last after I modified it. That's why I was asking for debugging.

Comment: @Santosh [This one works.](http://pastebin.com/8JSTvhKx) The blank line in the end is being inserted by the `print` function.

Comment: @ArturGaspar Really does that worked? I am still getting black line at last.

Comment: @Santosh Try writing it to a file instead of printing it, then open the output file in a text editor and see if it is right.

Comment: @ArturGaspar What do you mean by writing? Doing `python script.py input.txt > output.txt`? This way I still get a blank line at last.

Comment: @Santosh `f = open('outfile.txt', 'w'); f.write(capitalised); f.close()`.

Comment: @ArturGaspar One more modification. I want if third argument is given, then it take it as a output filename, if not it fallback to default `output.txt`

Comment: @Santosh Read the documentation of the `argparse` module. If you have already solved the blank line problem, ask another question.

Comment: @ArturGaspar Truly I'm not linking the way this script saves to file, I was good with doing `python script.py input.txt > output.txt`. Can you add few more lines of script to remove last line? Is it possible?

Comment: @Santosh What causes the extra line at the end is the `print` function. `sys.stdout.write(capitalised)` should not print the extra blank line.

Comment: @ArturGaspar You were wrong, I replaced `words = line.split(' ')` with `words = line.split()` and I got what I wanted.

Comment: @SantoshKumar `words = line.split()` will not preserve spacing.

Comment: @ArturGaspar You were right. `words = line.split()` does not preserve spacing. The problem is `words = line.split(' ')` creates a blank new line after writing every line. And `sys.stdout.write()` **only** removes newline from the last line. I can't use any one of them.

Answer (score 5):

```
for line in text_file:
    print ' '.join(word.title() if len(word) > 3 else word for word in line.split())
```

**Edit**: To omit counting punctuation replace `len` with the following function:

```
def letterlen(s):
    return sum(c.isalpha() for c in s)
```

Comment: Doesn't account for punctuation in computing length of word.

Comment: @martineau.  Edited to address your concern.

Comment: `word.title()` capitalises "can't" as "Can'T". `word.capitalize()`, which would capitalise only the first letter of `word`, may be used instead.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [NLTK](http://nltk.org/).

Tokenize each word, and capitalize it. Words such as 'if', 'of' are called 'stop words'. If your criteria is solely the length, Steven's answer is a good way of doing so. In case you want to look up stop words, there is a similar question in SO: [How to remove stop words using nltk or python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486337/stop-words-using-nltk-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is something called a list of [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words). In the absence of this list, you can build one yourself and do this:

```
skipWords = set("of is".split())
punctuation = '.,<>{}][()\'"/\\?!@#$%^&*' # and any other punctuation that you want to strip out
answer = ""

with open('filepath') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            for p in punctuation:
                # you end up losing the punctuation in the outpt. But this is easy to fix if you really care about it
                word = word.replace(p, '')  
            if word not in skipwords:
                answer += word.title() + " "
            else:
                answer += word + " "
    return answer # or you can write it to file continuously
```

Comment: Good approach, but needs to take into account for punctuation (which genrally aren't considered letters in a word).

Comment: Your update addresses the punctuation issue, but is done in what I suspect is a less than optimal, brute-force way.

Comment: @martineau How would you optimize it?

Comment: Well, for one thing you could create a punctuation set and use it to avoid the `for` loop which most words don't need. Second, the removal of the punctuation character could probably be done with a regex `re.sub()` or even a `str.translate()` unless the characters are unicode.

Comment: `re.sub` is a bit of an overkill and could get overly complex if used incorrectly (Fool rush in where angels fear to tread). But I do like the `str.translate` idea

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Heyy! I didn't wanted to escape only **of** and **is**, that was just an example. I want to escape any word which has 3 or less letters.

Comment: @Santosh: look at @Steven Rumbalski's answer. He uses `if len(word) > 3` to address that

Comment: Using `word.capitalize()` instead of `word.title()` avoids the need to remove punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

You could add all the elements from the text file to a list:

```
list = []
f.open('textdocument'.txt)
for elm in f (or text document, I\'m too tired):
   list.append(elm)
```

And once you have all the elements in a list, run a for loop that checks each element's length, and if it's greater than three returns the first element upper-cased

```
new_list = []
for items in list:
   if len(item) > 3:
      item.title()    (might wanna check if this works in this case)
      new_list.append(item)
   else:
   new_list.append(item)    #doesn't change words smaller than three words, just adds them to the new list
```

And see if that works?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-python    If my method of capitalization didn't work, try the methods mentioned here....

Comment: `for elm in f` will put each _line_ of the text file into the list, not each word. Your indentation on the last line is a little messed up.

Comment: Yeah I didn't copy/paste the code I wrote it in the form, which generally doesn't turn out well.