# convert a string such that the first letter is uppercase and everythingelse is lower case

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-python)

Is there an option to convert a string such that the first letter is uppercase and everythingelse is lower case....like below..i know there are upper and lower for converting to uppercase and lowercase....

> ```
> string.upper() //for uppercase 
> string.lower() //for lowercase
>  string.lower() //for lowercase
>
> INPUT:-italic,ITALIC
>
> OUTPUT:-Italic
> ```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: string.title()


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-python

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title

Comment: The "duplicate question" asks about how to capitalise the first letter of *each word* in the string; this question asks about how to capitalise only the first letter of the string.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just use `str.title()`:

```
In [73]: a, b = "italic","ITALIC"

In [74]: a.title(), b.title()
Out[74]: ('Italic', 'Italic')
```

help() on `str.title()`:

```
S.title() -> string

Return a titlecased version of S, i.e. words start with uppercase
characters, all remaining cased characters have lowercase.
```

Comment: This may or may not be correct depending on what you consider a "word". For example, `'some_words'.title()` results in `'Some_Words'`. If you consider a sequence of non-whitespace characters to be a "word", then @SuperFamousGuy has the right answer for you: `.capitalize()`.

Answer (score 18):

Yeah, just use the capitalize() method.

eg:

```
x = "hello"
x.capitalize()
print x   #prints Hello
```

Title will actually capitalize every word as if it were a title. Capitalize will only capitalize the first letter in a string.

Comment: +1 this will work fine for sentences.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it:

```
my_string = 'italic'
newstr = my_string[0]
newstr = newstr.upper()
my_string = newstr + my_string[1:]
```

To make them lowercase (except the first letter):

```
my_string= 'ITALIC'
newstr = my_string[1:]
newstr = newstr.lower()
my_string = my_string[0] + newstr
```

I don't know if there is a built in to do this, but this should work.