# How to capitalize each word after a space leaving the rest of it as is and preserve the space in the end if it exists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following procedure:

```
def capitalize(self, text):
    t = ' '.join([ ''.join([w[0].upper()]+[w[1:]]) for w in text.split()])
    if text and text[-1] == ' ':
        t = ''.join([t] + [' '])
    return t
```

It takes a string *text*.
What it's supposed to do:

- Capitalize first letter of each string group (word) coming after a space and preserve the space in the end of the text if there was any supplied.

ex:

```
'home swe eeeet home' -> 'Home Swe Eeeet Home'
'heLLo OoO ooo '      -> 'HeLLo OoO Ooo ' (space preserved in the end)
```

Question:

With my limited, totally non - expert level of Python, I tried to create this procedure as memory efficient and as fast as possible.

- Is the approach of converting things into list and joining them to not to keep creating a new string efficient in this case?
- Is there a better, more pythonic way to achieve this?

Furthermore:

This procedure is called each time a key is pressed onto a text field on a GUI application.

Comment: Duplicate posting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1549641/584846

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\b[a-z]', lambda m: m.group().upper(), 'home swe eeeet home')
'Home Swe Eeeet Home'
>>> re.sub(r'\b[a-z]', lambda m: m.group().upper(), 'heLLo OoO ooo ')
'HeLLo OoO Ooo '
```

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
>   occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the
>   pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl can be a
>   string or a function.
>
> If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
>   occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object
>   argument, and returns the replacement string.

`\b[a-z]` match any lowercase character(`[a-z]`) after the word boundary (`\b`).

The lambda function was used to convert the character to uppercase; [MatchObject.match](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) return match group. Without argument group 0 is assumed. Group 0 mean entire match string.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for actually reading the question. ;-) Seems like a rarity. This thing works like magic and does what it's supposed to. Do you think you could explain how it works though please? It would make it much better. Thank you, once again.

Comment: @Phil, I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
def title(s):
    return(' '.join(x.capitalize() for x in s.split(' ')))

# Or alternatively:
#y = []
#for x in s.split(' '): 
#    y.append(x.capitalize())
#return ' '.join(y)
```

Comment: Hello. This wouldn't work. Please read the question and see the provided examples.

Comment: Please add a small explanatory text which explains what syntax you used and how this is evaluated. It will help understanding what this one-liner does.