# Capitalize first letter of each word between [ and ] in text file

Tags: python, capitalize

EDIT: This question is different from other "capitalize first letter" questions because it requires capitalization only between "[" and "]".  Since the title was incomplete, I have edited it.

I have a text file in which I need to reformat the text.

I have tried to loop lines and words while the file is open in 'r+', but have been unsuccessful.

Here is a sample:

```
Create Table Data(
    [SOME ID] int,
    [LAST NAME] varchar(30),
    [FIRST NAME] varchar(30),
    [TLA THING] smallint,
    [TLA THING REMARK] varchar(255)
)
```

I would like the first letter in each word between the [ ] to be capitalized.  And as a bonus I'd love spaces between [ ] to be replaced with underscores.

code I tried:

```
f = open('somescript.sql','r+')
for line in f:
    for word in line:
        word.capitalize()
```

I also tried `f.write(word.capitalize())` instead of just `word.capitalize`.  All results were equally tragic.

Comment: Equally tragic? :) Meaning nothing changed in the file? Did something else happen? Do specify.

Comment: 1. file opened in wrong mode, 2. once you read a file file pointer shifted so you are not overwriting logic is wrong 3. Create a new file write in that and  delete this-old file and rename that file.

Comment: what about something like `IRS` or `camelCase` `Hyphenated-Words`?

Comment: Are those square brackets actually present in your file? Or are you just using them to signify placeholder text? Can you provide sample input/output exactly as they would appear?

Comment: @batbrat apologies for the color. equally tragic meant both were failures.  One ended up with an empty file and the other with millions more lines than I started with.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I've already replaced hyphens.  There are not currently any concatenated words.  There are some capitalized acronyms, but I'm not particularly concerned with preserving their capitalization.

Comment: @AlexThornton I looked there, but I'll double-check.

Comment: @Kevin They are actually present in the sql script.  SQL Server uses them to allow non-standard field names.  The actual scripts I'll be changing were generated by another software.

Comment: @StephenLloyd, thanks for clarifying. I'm glad you've solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would code this :

1. load the whole content of your file
2. use the module `re` (`re.sub` would help) to transform parts that need to be
3. overwrite the file with the transformed text

The implementation :

```
txt = # load your file
pattern = re.compile(r"\[(.*)\]")
transform = lambda mo : mo.group(0).title().replace(" ", "_")
new_txt = pattern.sub(transform, txt)
# write new text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `.title()` method asked here in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-python). Also, make sure that you write the changes back to the file with `f.write()`. Just having the mode as r+ doesn't persist anything to the file for you.

```
f = open('somescript.sql','r+'):
text = f.read()
text = text.title()
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to your problem, it uses `regex` to handle the actual replacements, but this could easily be completed by writing your own parser.

Using this as my test inp

```
text = '''Create Table Data(
    [lower case id] int,
    [loser case last name] varchar(30),
    [lower case first name] varchar(30),
    [lower case tla thing] smallint,
    [lower case tla thing remark] varchar(255)
)
'''
```

The process is then simply to simply format each match the `regex` expression makes.

```
def format_input(val):
    val = val.strip()
    val = val.split()
    new_val = ""
    for word in val:
        new_val += word[0].upper() + word[1:] + "_"
    return new_val[:-1] //Remove the trailing underscore


content = ""
with open('mySQLfile.sql','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        content += line

import re
content = re.sub(r'\[(.*?)\]',lambda m: '['+format_input(m.group(1))+']',content,re.M)

with open('mySQLfile.sql','w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

And without the use of `regex`:

```
new_content = ""
buf = ""
in_tag = False
for i in content:
    if in_tag:
        buf += i
    else:
        new_content += i
    if i == '[':
        in_tag = True
    elif i == ']':
        in_tag = False
        new_content += format_input(buf)
        buf = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open present file `somescript.sql'` in read mode. Read each line and process it e.g. if there is a column name then capitalized first latter and replace space by _ This can be  done using regular expression. Latter you can delete old file and rename temp file as old-filed name.

**script.py:**

```
import os, re
with open("somescript.sql") as i: # open sql file for reading 
  with open("temp", "w") as o: # tem file for writing 
    for l in i: # read line by line 
      c = re.match(r".*\[(?P<col_name>.*)\].*", l) # use re to find col_name
      if c: # if column name found  
        c = c.group('col_name') # change col name 
        o.write(l.replace('['+c+']', '['+c.title().replace(' ', '_'))+']')
      else:       #         ^^ col name titled and replace every space by _  
        o.write(l)
os.remove("somescript.sql") # delete old file 
os.rename("temp", "somescript.sql")  # rename file
```

I did as follows, I have two files:

```
answer$ ls
script.py  somescript.sql
```

somescript file is:

```
answer$ cat somescript.sql 
Create Table Data(
    [SOME ID] int,
    [LAST NAME] varchar(30),
    [FIRST NAME] varchar(30),
    [TLA THING] smallint,
    [TLA THING REMARK] varchar(255)
)

$ python script.py  # run script 
/answer$ cat somescript.sql 
Create Table Data(
    [Some_Id] int,
    [Last_Name] varchar(30),
    [First_Name] varchar(30),
    [Tla_Thing] smallint,
    [Tla_Thing_Remark] varchar(255)
)
```

To explain: `o.write(l.replace(c, c.title().replace(' ', '_')))`

1. `o.write(x)` write a string `x` in file
2. `l.replace(c, c.title().replace(' ', '_'))` replace first argument `c` that is a column name by second argument `c.title().replace(' ', '_')`, Second argument is `c` titled followed by space is replaced by `_`.