# Python change a single character of a string

Tags: python, string, uppercase

I have a string named userName in my program. It holds a users name and I want to be able to change it's first letter to a capital if not already.

For example if userName = "john"
I want it to change too "John"

I attempted this:

```
userClass[1] = userClass[1].upper()
```

That does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am on Python 3 not 2!

Comment: `userClass.title()` would do that for you.

Comment: duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-python)

Comment: Strings are immutable. Once it has been created, elements can't be changed.