# Capitalize First Character of word in string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have strings like following: i have tried .title() and capitalize() but not successes.

Input

```
"hello world"
"1hello world"
"hello   world  lol"
"1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9"
"1 w 2 r 3g"
"132 456 Wq  m e"
"q w e r t y u i o p a s d f g h j  k l z x c v b n m Q W E R T Y U I O P A S D F G H J  K L Z X C V B N M"
```

Output

```
"Hello World"
"1hello World"
"Hello   World  Lol"
"1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9"
"1 W 2 R 3g"
"132 456 Wq  M E"
"Q W E R T Y U I O P A S D F G H J  K L Z X C V B N M Q W E R T Y U I O P A S D F G H J  K L Z X C V B N M"
```

I have try this also, but when input string with more then one space then its got error.

```
str = "Hello   World  Lol"
for i in range(0,len(new)):
    str += new[i][0].upper() + new[i][1:] + " "
print str
```

Comment: what do you want to do exaclty?

Comment: When I do `"hello world".title()` on my machine, I get `"Hello World"`. Is that not what you get? What do you get? You _are_ assigning the result or displaying it, right? Note that strings are immutable, so if you so `s = "hello world"; s.title(); print(s)`, it will still print the uncapitalized version.

Comment: Why doesn't `.title()` work? How is it any different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string (Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-python)

Comment: `.title()` work for me also. Not sure why for author it does not.

Comment: i want to capitalize first character of word without losing  space and if first character is number then leave it as it is

Comment: @m0nhawk with .title()  if string is "1hello world" it will capitalize "1Hello World" i dont want to capitalize second character. output should be "1hello World"

Comment: you can you `capitalize()` method check below answer.

Comment: @Bhansa your answer worked! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context you can use `capitalize()` method.

```
str = "Helo  w world lol"
lista = []
for i in str.split(" "):
    lista.append(i.capitalize())
print " ".join(lista) #"Helo  W World Lol"
```

Using list comprehension:

```
print " ".join([i.capitalize() for i in str.split(" ")])
```

Answer (score 3):

How have you tried `.title()`? `str.title()` should return the capitalised string but bear in mind strings are immutable so you will have to assign it to a new value.

```
string1 = "hello   world  lol"
string2 = string1.title()
```

Comment: it will not work in "1hello world" i need output "1hello World"