# Capitalize letter with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
names = ['one', 'two']
print([n[0].upper() for n in names])
```

**I want output like this:**
   One, Two

how can I do this with python?

Comment: Why are you adding [0]?

Comment: @roganjosh Probably trying to target the first character.

Comment: Should `'oNe'` be `'One'` or `'ONe'`? Because that matters when you use `.title()`.

Comment: A lot of detailed discussion in this very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-python

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> names = ['one', 'two']
>>> names = [n.title() for n in names]
>>> names
['One', 'Two']
>>>
```

If you want it to work with a capital letter in it like `oNe` will be `ONe` then:

```
>>> names = ['oNe', 'twO']
>>> names = [n[0].upper()+n[1:] if n else "" for n in names]
>>> names
['ONe', 'TwO']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the method 'capitalize()' of the Python Standard Library.Here is the code :

```
names = ['one', 'two']
print([n.capitalize() for n in names])
```

So, you will get this output: **['One', 'Two']**