# having first letter in upper case and all other letters in lower case in text6 of nltk

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am doing some hands-Ons online in python for nltk.

The task is to filter words from complete set of Text6 having first letter in upper case and all other letters in lower case.
Print the number of words present.

Can someone please assist to tell the exact answer (as it is standard text from book of nltk) and what's wrong in the code.

I tried below code:

```
from nltk.book import text6
import re
pattern = '[A-Z]+[a-z]+$'
capsword= [word for word in set(text6) if re.search(pattern, word)]
print(len(capsword))
```

My actual output is 461.
But, I am not sure about expected output as same is hidden.

Comment: Post a sample output please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-python)

Comment: I don't have any expected output. same is hidden.
But when I execute this code..it is not accepting.
As per the task requirement, the count(numeric value only) of words is expected.

I also print the 'capsword' list...and can see all words are matching the filter.

Comment: @Robson: I need to count the existing words (the link provided is to do update for words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the pattern (to include special char words like ABC! or ABC.) and it worked:

```
from nltk.book import text6
import re
pattern = '[A-Z][a-z*]'
a = [word for word in set(text6) if (re.search(pattern, word))]
print(len(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, it worked for me on Fresco Play

```
from nltk.book import text6    
title_words = [word for word in text6 if word.istitle()]

print(len(title_words))

Output: 2672
```

As per the challenge, we are supposed to use complete set of words in text6.

**istitle()** method returns **True** for words with first letter in upper case and all other letters in lower case