# Using title() function for capitalizing printed sentence

Tags: python, isnumeric

I am looking a way to assign value to printed sentence to capitalize the first letters. The output should be: "Hello World!". This is my current code and the answer is "HELLO NEW WORLD" as a.title capitalizes every letter:

```
well='13H3e1llo0 312w20orl3d!432'
for a in well:
    if a.isnumeric()==False:
        print(a.title())
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try using separate steps in the code to figure out the string without digits, and *then* applying `title` to that? Do you understand how to *create a new string* from the letters, rather than `print`ing each one as it's found?

Comment: The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) are very useful in this situation

Comment: Don't do things like `if a.isnumeric()==False:` (i.e. don’t compare boolean values to `True` or `False` using `==`). `a.isnumeric()` is already a bool. Just `if not a.isnumeric():`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I capitalize the first letter of each word in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string)

Comment: Where does the `"NEW"` in `"HELLO NEW WORLD"` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `a.title()` works perfectly if we have `a='hello world'` but here you have used a `for` loop which means `.title()` is invoked for each alphabetical character and capitalizes it. We con do this way:

```
alphstr = ''
for char in well:
    if char.isnumeric() == False:
        alphstr += char
print(alphstr.title())
```

Hope you find it useful.