# Loops getting stuck at the wrong part in python

Tags: while-loop

For Some reason the loop wont carry out the command of yes and instead it just keeps repeating at the incorrect part

i tried changing the while to an if and it didn't help, I'm not sure why it doesn't work

```
FA=input ('Are there assignments to grade? Yes/No:')#FA refers to whether or not there are assignments to grade
FA=FA.upper()

while FA not in ('Yes', 'No'):
   print ('Please enter a valid input: either Yes or No')
   FA=input('Are there any assingments to grade? Yes/No:')
   FA=FA.upper()


#outputs
while FA == 'Yes':
```

Comment: I think you mean `FA.title()`. `.upper()` changes all characters in the string to upper case (so you would need to compare with `("YES", "NO")`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I capitalize the first letter of each word in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549641/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

The loop is getting stuck because of `FA=FA.upper()`. Because for example if the user inputs `Yes` the string gets converted to uppercase i.e. `YES` which is interpreted differently from `Yes`.

If you are converting the input string to uppercase then you'll have to use uppercase strings to check for correct input.

Below is the correct way to check for input.

```
while FA not in ('YES', 'NO'): // Use uppercase strings to check if input was valid
   print ('Please enter a valid input: either Yes or No')
   FA=input('Are there any assingments to grade? Yes/No:')
   FA=FA.upper() // Changes all letters to uppercase
```

Comment: that works i forgot about that. thanks for helping with my blunder.